# How to check if a timestamp is a whole hour

Tags: python, timestamp, modulo, epoch

I'm building a python application where I get a lot of data from various timeseries (ranging from 1 minute to 1 day). I would only like to store the times (unix timestamps) that are exactly on a whole hour (xx:00 minutes). How do I build this check?

Is a simple `if timestamp % 3600 == 0: save the timestamp` sufficient enough? Or is there a better way?

Comment: use module `time` or `datetime`

Comment: like exectly whole hour means 11:00 or 10:00 like that???

Comment: @Hackaholic Yes that is exactly what I mean.And I see I used modulo 60. That should be modulo 3600 (I want whole hours, not minutes)

Comment: show us ur data on waht you want to perform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timestamp is in seconds, so the time mod 3600 should be zero.

```
if timestamp % 3600 == 0:
    # save the timestamp-value tuple
```

This is enough, you don't have to make a datetime object and check the minute and second for every timestamp you get.

Answer (score 5):

use [datetime.fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp)

```
from datetime import datetime  

ts = 1415309268
cts = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
print(cts.minute==00)
```

If you want seconds also:

```
cts.minute==00 and cts.second==00
```

Comment: cts.second u can use in here

Comment: @Andrey, op only seemed to want minutes, I will add seconds in case

Comment: @PadraicCunningham he said whole hour, so possibly that he didn't himself think of seconds :)

Comment: @Andrey, I went by  (xx:00 minutes) but you are probably correct ;)